# Angular $http.post request returns 404 unexpectedly

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory as follows:

```
MyApp.factory('DB_Services', function($http , $q) {
    var l_Result ;
    var DB_Services = function(p_Query) {
                            var l_deferred = $q.defer();
                            var l_url      = "http://MyWeb.com:8080/Services/Dispatcher?";
                            var l_params   = '{"data":' + JSON.stringify(p_Query) + '}' ;
        
                            console.log("DB_Services - l_params: " + l_params ) ;

                            $http.post( {
                                               url:l_url,
                                               method:"POST",
                                               headers: {
                                                          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                               },
                                               data: l_params
                                          }
                            ).
                                        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                             l_deferred.resolve(data);
                                        }).
                                        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                            console.log("DB_Services - Error: " + data) ;
                                             l_deferred.reject(status);
                                        });
                                         return l_deferred.promise;

                        } ;

return DB_Services;
});
```

When invoking the DB_Services, my browser (Chrome) shows in the CONSOLE the following:

1. The request data as:

   DB_Services - l_params: `{"data":{"Action":"Get_Landing_Page_Messages","Request_Details":{"Language_Code":"EN"}}}`
2. The print I added to the error as:

   DB_Services - Error: Cannot POST /[object%20Object]
3. The following additional error:

   POST [http://127.0.0.1:55402/[object%20Object]](http://127.0.0.1:55402/%5Bobject%20Object%5D) 404 (Not Found)

I tried several possible syntaxes for the `data`, none worked.

There s a servlet `http://MyWeb.com:8080/Services/Dispatcher` that handles both GET and POST requests. When I issue a GET request by entering a similar data string into the address bar of Chrome, I do get the result as expected.

I can't understand what the issue is.

Comment: It seems that the issue is that you add URL inside the object you are posting. Thus post can't know where to post your object. According to AngularJS documentation http post is defined following: `$http.post(url, data, [config])`. So you need to separate your url data from the object. Check more specific details at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the invocation as suggested, and now I get the following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://MyWeb.com:8080/Services/Dispatcher?request=. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:55402' is therefore not allowed access.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of post method is an URL, the second one is an object with parameters, so both of these should work, depending on your backend:

```
$http.post(l_url, {data: l_params}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
$http.post(l_url, l_params).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

see here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I get the following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://MyWeb.com:8080/Services/Dispatcher?request=. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:55402' is therefore not allowed access.`. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: var req = {
 url: l_url,
 method:"POST",
 headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 },
 data: l_params
}

$http(req).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: Added `req` and a print of it getting `DB_Services - req is: {"url":"http://MyWeb.com:8080/Services/Dispatcher?request=","method":"POST","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"data":"{\"data\":{\"Action\":\"Get_Landing_Page_Messages\",\"Request_Details\":{\"Language_Code\":\"EN\"}}}"}`. Now, I'm getting back the original error of my initial post.

Comment: You have probably done it like so: $http.post(req), but I want you to try $http(req).

Comment: Did it and got `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://MyWeb.com:8080/Services/Dispatcher?request=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:55402' is therefore not allowed access.`.

Comment: OK. After some struggle, it turned out that there was something missing in the TOPCAT configuration. Now it works ALMOST perfectly. The only (small) problem left with this is that none-latin chars are shown as "?". Will open a new question for that. Thanks!!!!